# How to Auto Fill Filds while Adding Certificate to Profile on Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to add Add In Profile Button in my website for the certification so that user can add it to their linked in profile.
For this I am using

```
<div><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="https://download.linkedin.com/desktop/add2profile/buttons/en_US.png " alt="LinkedIn Add to Profile button"></a></div>
```

can anyone help here that how to autofile fileds ? means I want to send certificate name, link, licence from my end. so that user no need to type there. 
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find anything, all the docs online says you can't anymore, I don't understand as the functionality is pretty useless without pre filling

Comment: I'm really frustrated with this. I really don't understand who linkedin is not considering the User Experience on this.

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking into this, and it looks like it's a non-starter.

From: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/61169

(No idea how recent this is, but it's the closest to a solid answer that I could find)

> We’ve recently made some changes to our Add to Profile functionality, which will impact how third-party information is populated into fields on a LinkedIn member’s profile.
>
> Specifically, if a member wants to add certification or degree fields to their profile, they can continue to do so using the Add to Profile button. However, it will no longer autofill and members must enter the relevant information directly on their profile.
>
> Developers who implement Add to Profile can now use a static URL to generate their button. Links will no longer be customized for a specific certificate or degree. After clicking Add to Profile, users will be directed to a profile form where they can fill out the details of their certificate or degree. Existing customized buttons will continue to work, but they’ll now direct to the new experience without auto-filling certificate or degree information.

That said, there is still an [API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/certification) that seems to indicate the ability to add a certification to a profile, but I haven't dug into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format

```
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&name=Name certification&organizationId=IDINSTITUTION&issueYear=2023&issueMonth=12
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.